# How to return field validation errors in nested formGroups?

Tags: angular, validation, angular-services, angular4-forms

I'm creating a utility function to catch all form field validation errors, on form submit, using Angular 4 reactive forms.

I have multiple instances of nested FormGroups within these forms - for example: two nested 'address' formGroups (for home & delivery). *NB: these are only nested one level deep within the parent formGroup.*

**Currently I can only get this to work with one nested formGroup as per the below code.**

How can I get this to work on forms which have multiple instances of nested formGroups, without creating another level to the for loop below..

I've been down the route of recursive function (commented in code) but the 'return' statement runs before the recursive function completes and outputs an empty array...

Really appreciate your help with this guys.

```
// utilities.service.ts

const focus: string = UtilitiesService.getAllFormErrors(formGroup)[0];


public static getAllFormErrors(formGroup: FormGroup): string[] {
    let fieldName: string[] = [];

    for (const value in formGroup.controls) {
        const ctrl = formGroup.get(value);
        if (ctrl instanceof FormGroup) {

        // tried calling recursive function here - this.getAllFormErrors(ctrl);

            // loop around new formControls in nested FormGroup
            for (const value in ctrl.controls) {

            const nestedCtrl = ctrl.get(value);
                if (nestedCtrl.errors !== null) {
                    fieldName.push(value);
                }
            }
        } else if (ctrl.errors !== null) {
            fieldName.push(value);
        }
    }
    return fieldName;
}

// expect the 'focus' variable to return the first field throwing a validation error
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar. This is what my generic validator code looks like (see below).

Note that I did use recursion to process multiple form groups.

```
  // Processes each control within a FormGroup
  // And returns a set of validation messages to display
  // Structure
  // controlName1: 'Validation Message.',
  // controlName2: 'Validation Message.'
  processMessages(container: FormGroup): { [key: string]: string } {
    const messages = {};
    for (const controlKey in container.controls) {
      if (container.controls.hasOwnProperty(controlKey)) {
        const c = container.controls[controlKey];
        // If it is a FormGroup, process its child controls.
        if (c instanceof FormGroup) {
          const childMessages = this.processMessages(c);
          Object.assign(messages, childMessages);
        } else {
          // Only validate if there are validation messages for the control
          if (this.validationMessages[controlKey]) {
            messages[controlKey] = '';
            if ((c.dirty || c.touched) && c.errors) {
              Object.keys(c.errors).map(messageKey => {
                if (this.validationMessages[controlKey][messageKey]) {
                  messages[controlKey] += this.validationMessages[controlKey][messageKey] + ' ';
                }
              });
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return messages;
  }
```

You can find the complete application here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-ReactiveForms/tree/master/APM

I used a key/value pair structure instead of a simple array so I could retain both the field name and the error message. I then used Object.assign to merge the structure returned from the recursive method code to the "master" structure.